# How to merge other branch into my branch?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm fairly new to Git and working in a team that uses Github. I was told to branch from `master` to `myBranch`, which I did and pushed to Github. Now the `master` has been branched to `theirBranch` by the team leader and he has asked me to "build on top of" `theirBranch` (whatever that means).

I tried various options and got confused with merge conflicts and other errors. In the end this one stumped me:

```
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
```

So I decided to trash the entire local repo and reclone from GitHub. I am working on only one file, which I have manually backed up somewhere. So I would like `myBranch` to have a fresh start from `theirBranch` and then manually replace that one file.

I used the commands:

```
git clone <github_repo>
git checkout myBranch
git merge -X theirs myBranch theirBranch
```

It did something but I'm not sure if its what I want. How do I find out what was actually done in merge and which branch was modified?

Also, any references to learn Git for these tasks would be appreciated as this doesn't seem to be the best way to work.

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble with the Git basics and with how your team is using Git. You should [read up on Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and ask your team lead for some help with their process.

Comment: On your branch just do: `git merge theirBranch` or `git pull origin theirBranch`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read something about git first because it's not safe to use that way. 
After `git clone repo`

1. `git checkout -b <your branch name>`
2. Make some changes in files
3. `git commit -a -m "test_commit"`
4. `git checkout <branch_merge_to>`
5. `git merge <branch_to_merge>`
6. If there is no conflicts, push it to github
7. `git push <merged_branch>`

I would like to recommend you do some git actions in training repository.